# jQuery trigger function not working on ajax generated content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-trigger

**Code**
How to fire click trigger on ajax generated html tag

**Is Working**

```
$(document).on("click","#Copyright #disclaimer_btn_trg",function(e){
    alert($( "#DesclaimerButton span" ).html());
});
```

**Is Notworking**

```
$(document).on("click","#Copyright #disclaimer_btn_trg",function(e){
    //alert($( "#DesclaimerButton span" ).html());
    $( "#DesclaimerButton span" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

Comment: how is the event handler registered... use event delegation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements